What PropertyName does ListBox in WPF bind to when using DisplayMemberPath?
I'm learning how to build more sophisticated data structures, and how to bind them in WPF. Given the datastructure below, I can't figure out how to call OnPropertyChanged() so that the ListBox updates correctly. What PropertyName is ListBox looking for?
MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="GUITest2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUITest2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding container}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Height="100"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30" Width="80"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections;

namespace GUITest2;

public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public People container { get; set; } = new();
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void Button() {
        container.Add("Harry");
    }
}

public class People : ObservableObject, IEnumerable<People.Person> {
    readonly List<Person> _dataList = new();

    public People() {
        _dataList.Add(new Person() { Name = "Bob" });
        _dataList.Add(new Person() { Name = "Jeff" });
    }

    public void Add(string Name) {
        OnPropertyChanging("Name");
        _dataList.Add(new Person() { Name = Name });
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");

    }

    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator() {
        return _dataList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return ((IEnumerable)_dataList).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public class Person {
        public string Name { get; internal set; } = "";
    }
}


For the list box to be informed about changes in the collection (add/remove), the collection must implement INotifyCollectiomChanged. Usually one would use ObservableCollection for this. If it shall also react on changes in Person.Name, the Person class must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

There is no need for your People class.
In real life you would rarely encounter a situation where you need to implement a collection with change notification yourself, i.e. where you have to write a class that implements INotifyCollectionChanged or derives from ObservableCollection.
You would instead declare a (read-only) ObservableCollection property.
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}

Use it with this Binding:
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>

In order to add elements to the collection and thus update the UI, call
People.Add(new Person() { Name = "Bob" });


For your question about DisplayMemberPath, it refers to a property of the element type of the ItemsSource collection that is used for display. It is essentially the same as writing this:
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

For more details, see Data Templating Overview.

I only wanted to expose an IEnumerable. If I use ObservableCollection, then that exposes a lot of methods that allow outside callers to mutate the data. I could override them, but I would rather just implement my own class with my own methods only expose what I want. I'm trying to use this to enforce strong compiletime checking to ensure that the internal data doesn't become accidentally mutated by an external caller.

Who should be that "external caller" of a property in your MainWindow class?

And you may of course only expose an IEnumerable like public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>(); 

Or you expose the property as ReadOnlyObservableCollection.

Make your People class to derive from ObservableCollection than ObservableObject. It comes with everything you need to make the ListBox in-sync with the People instance.
public class People : ObservableCollection<People.Person> {
    public People() {
        this.Add(new Person() { Name = "Bob" });
        this.Add(new Person() { Name = "Jeff" });
    }

    public class Person {
        public string Name { get; internal set; } = "";
    }
}

or, even better, if you're using NET Desktop 8:
public class People : ObservableCollection<People.Person> {
    public People()
        : base([
            new Person() { Name = "Bob" },
            new Person() { Name = "Jeff" },
            ])
    {
    }

    public class Person {
        public string Name { get; internal set; } = "";
    }
}

Furthermore, any reason to define the Person class as part of the People one?
Moreover, about the container property.

Since that's a (public) property, stick to the naming convention as the Pascal-casing says, hence adjust to Container (with upper capital).

Here is not clear your intention: it is an init-only property, or rather could be changed over time?


In first case, change its signature as follows, to prevent misleading settings, which will no projected to the XAML side:
public People Container { get; init; } = new();

or:
public People Container { get; } = new();

Otherwise, just implement the PropertyChanged pattern or, even better, as a DependencyProperty. However, that's a little complex, if you are a novice.

See the comment above. I don't want to use ObservableCollection. Person class is part of People class so that People class can access the setter of Person. This ensures any modification to Person must be done through the People classes' methods.

I think this implementation will help you:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfCommunityToolkit.SO.systemloc.Question78322667
{
    public partial class Person : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _name = string.Empty;
    }
}

using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfCommunityToolkit.SO.systemloc.Question78322667
{
    public partial class PeopleViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; }
            =
            [
                new Person() { Name = "Bob" },
                new Person() { Name = "Jeff" }
            ];

        [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanAddPerson))]
        private void AddPerson(Person person)
        {
            People.Add(person);
        }

        private bool CanAddPerson(Person person)
        {
            return !(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person?.Name) ||
                People.Any(p => p.Name.Equals(person.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
        }

        [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanRemovePerson))]
        private void RemovePerson(Person person)
        {
            People.Remove(person);
        }

        private bool CanRemovePerson(Person person)
        {
            return People.Contains(person);
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfCommunityToolkit.SO.systemloc.Question78322667.PeopleWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCommunityToolkit.SO.systemloc.Question78322667"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="PeopleWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PeopleViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
        <local:Person Name="qwerty" x:Key="addingPerson"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <UniformGrid Columns="1">
            <Button Content="Add Person"
                Margin="10" Padding="15 5"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Command="{Binding AddPersonCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                CommandParameter="{DynamicResource addingPerson}"/>
            <Button Content="Remove Selected Person"
                Margin="10" Padding="15 5"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Command="{Binding RemovePersonCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox}"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>

P.S. I want to warn you.
Judging by the code you are using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. This package does not provide automatic revalidation of WPF commands. In this case, you will have to use some additional code to call revalidation.

The People object is part of a larger model that gets touched by a lot of different code.

Without knowing your implementation, I can't give an exact answer. The code I showed is a generalized example. Its important features.

If the Person.Name property can be changed, then the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event must be raised to update its representation.
For normal, convenient work with WPF elements, you need to set the Data Context. In your case, one of the properties of this Data Context (PeopleViewModel) should be an ObservableCollection (or any other with an INotifyCollectionChanged or IBindingList implementation).
For buttons you need to create commands in the Data Context. This makes implementation much easier.


The People object is part of a larger model that gets touched by a lot of different code.

@systemloc I have expanded my answer.

"P.S. I want to warn you..." Thank you! I'm sure that would have cause me a bug down the road.

Implementing INotifyCollectionChanged caused the code to work, as mentioned in the comment on the question. I spent a lot of time digging through the internals of ListBox in the debugger to see where it is binding to the event, though, and I still can't find it. It seems CollectionChanged works, and PropertyChanged doesn't, but I can't find documentation of what events ListBox will listen for. Note: This is not a complete implementation. I kept it very terse for demonstration.
public class People : ObservableObject, INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable<People.Person> {
    readonly List<Person> _dataList = new();

    public People() {
        _dataList.Add(new Person() { Name = "Bob" });
        _dataList.Add(new Person() { Name = "Jeff" });
    }

    protected void OnCollectionChanged() {
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler? CollectionChanged;

    public void Add(string Name) {
        _dataList.Add(new Person() { Name = Name });
        OnCollectionChanged();
    }

    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator() {
        return _dataList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return ((IEnumerable)_dataList).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public class Person {
        public string Name { get; internal set; } = "";
    }
}


It is also extremely inefficient to always fire the CollectionChanged event with NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset, as that would indicate to a target UI element that the whole collection has been reset or replaced and that for example all ListBoxItems in a ListBox would have to be re-created or re-initialized.

It is also questionable how your self-written "collection class with notification" differs from an ordinary ObservableCollection. The Add method is public, so that your assumed "external caller" can call it in the same way it could for ObservableCollection. It looks pretty much like you are confusing things here, and should really be taking a look at ReadOnlyObservableCollection.

@systemloc Clemens (and I) shown you several ways to implement what you need, also by protecting from external modifications. BTW, you likely mixing immutability with observability. Why do you insist with bad code?

clemens, Here, I only implemented reset as a demonstration. I haven't yet figured out how to make Add(Person person) private. Thanks for pointing out ReadOnlyObservableCollection. I'll probably use it. Add() throws, though, so it's a runtime error rather than a compiletime error, which is undesirable, but probably the best solution possible. Varnari, I'm trying to dig into the internals a bit to better understand how things work. I learned a lot by digging into this.
